# I am getting field integrity exception for this code

Tags: lightning-aura-components

[image]

```
<aura:component description="ChatBotService" controller="LexChatBotCtrl" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="chatList" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="userChat" type="String"/>
    <div class="demo-only slds-grid" style="height:340px;max-width:340px;background:#f4f6f9;padding:1rem;">
        <div class="slds-panel slds-grid slds-grid_vertical slds-nowrap">
            <div class="slds-form slds-form_stacked slds-grow slds-scrollable_y">
                <div class="slds-panel__section slds-border_bottom">
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.chatList}" var="chatItem">
                        <div> 
                            <span class="slds-badge">{!chatItem.userName}</span>
                            <p>
                                {!chatItem.chatText}
                            </p>
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="demo-only slds-grid" style="height:100px;max-width:340px;background:#f4f6f9;padding:1rem;">
        <div class="slds-panel slds-grid slds-grid_vertical slds-nowrap">
            <div class="slds-form slds-form_stacked slds-grow slds-scrollable_y">
                <div class="slds-panel__section slds-border_bottom">
                    <ui:inputText class="slds-input" value="{!v.userChat}" keyup="{!c.postUserChat}" placeholder="Chat here ..." /> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

---

```
/**
* AWS_LEX_CHATBOT Client side controller
*/
({
    postUserChat: function(component, event, helper) {
        if (event.getParams().keyCode !== 13) {
            return;
        }
        var chatList = component.get(“v.chatList”);
        var action = component.get(“c.postChatText”);
        chatList.push({“
            chatText”: component.get(“v.userChat”),
            “userName”: ‘Me: ‘
        });
        action.setParams({“
            chatText”: component.get(“v.userChat”)
        });
        component.set(“v.userChat”, “”);
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var data = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
            chatList.push({“
                chatText”: data.message,
                “userName”: ‘Personal Assistant: ‘
            });
            component.set(“v.chatList”, chatList);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take the [tour]. Please don't post error messages as screenshots, as it is not as accessible to users that use screen readers or other assistive technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has numerous problems.

First, you used smart quotes (`“`, `”`, '‘') in your code, instead of `"` and `'`.

Second, you have line breaks in some of your strings. This is illegal in JavaScript:

```
"
chatText":
```

Make sure everything is on one line:

```
"chatText":
```

Third, you have a mismatched `}` in your code (line 27 in my editor, including comments).

Fixed Code:

```
/**
 * AWS_LEX_CHATBOT Client side controller
 */
({
  postUserChat: function (component, event, helper) {
    if (event.getParams().keyCode !== 13) {
      return;
    }
    var chatList = component.get("v.chatList");
    var action = component.get("c.postChatText");
    chatList.push({ chatText: component.get("v.userChat"), userName: "Me: " });
    action.setParams({ chatText: component.get("v.userChat") });
    component.set("v.userChat", "");
    action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
      var data = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
      chatList.push({
        chatText: data.message,
        userName: "Personal Assistant: ",
      });
      component.set("v.chatList", chatList);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  },
})
```

You may have additional problems in your code, but this should at least *save*.

Comment: it is working for save

Comment: Still i am getting error "This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: c:Amazon_Lex_Chatbot$controller$postUserChat [userChat is not defined]
Failing descriptor: {c:Amazon_Lex_Chatbot$controller$postUserChat}"